# Spring mvc redirect from one controller to another works but another controller don't open page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

The problem is following. I have one controller-class with post-method that redirect to another controller-class with get-method. In debugging mode i step into post-method then it redirect to get-method and it works correctly. But code `return "journals/doc/index";` doesn't work, because i'm staying on the same page i called the post-method. At the same time there are no errors.
Of course, I expect to go to the journals/doc/index page instead of staying on the previous page.
Please tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks for any help!

```
// My first controller
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myProject/journals/doc")
public class DOCController {

   @PostMapping("/create")
    public String create(@RequestBody String dataToSave) throws JsonProcessingException {

        // code to create object in database using JPARepository ...

        return "redirect:/myProject/journals/doc";
    }

}

// My second controller
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myProject/journals/doc")
public class ViewDocController {

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("viewDocs", viewDocService.getAll());
        return "journals/doc/index"; // it doesn't work
    }

}
```

`EDIT`

The resource `journals/doc/index` exists and availble. When i type the URL `localhost:8080/myProject/journals/doc` in the browser the page `index.html` opens. But the page `index.html` doesn't open after `redirect:/myProject/journals/doc` from controller.

Comment: Spring boot doesn't have an option to browse directory unless you add it to the server.

Comment: The directory `myProject/journals/doc` exists on the server and in the directory exists file index.html. As far as i know if directory doesn't exist it will be the error 404.

Comment: 404 is a error code is common for web application. It establish a fact that a requested resource is not available dispight your previous comment.

Comment: @RomanC I think it's not that the resource is unavailable, because the link `localhost:8080/myProject/journals/doc` specified in the url string works and the page index.html opens correctly. It doesn't work only after `redirect:/myProject/journals/doc`.

Comment: `redirect:/myProject/journals/doc` is going to `localhost:8080/myProject/journals/doc` isn't it? And you said that it works because it opens `index.html`.

Comment: @RomanC I mean, when I type the URL `localhost:8080/myProject/journals/doc` in the browser the page `index.html` opens. But the page `index.html` doesn't open after `redirect:/myProject/journals/doc` from controller.

Comment: When you send redirect from the controller  the browser is going to `localhost:8080/myProject/journals/doc`. Debug your browser before it opens index html.

Comment: @RomanC After redirect in debugger mode in my ide, I come to the `return "journals/doc/index";` then i execute it and nothing happens. There are no errors in the ide, there are no errors in the browser, and I remain on the same page from which I sent the redirect. this is a problem.

Comment: You said it opens an index.html. As I mentioned in the previous comment there's no difference to direct the browser to the location specified. Why it's going to your controller? It's not usual behaviour. The browser not redirect themselves to the index html. Why it takes precidance to enter the url manualy and not hit by the controller but instead a default servlet?

Comment: @RomanC Unfortunately, I do not know the answer to this question. I found a solution, it's hardly the best solution, but it works. See my answer. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I called my post method `create(@RequestBody String data To Save)` from ajax, like this

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/myProject/journals/doc/create',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("input[name='_csrf']").val()},
        data : JSON.stringify({document, plbTable}),

        error: function (jqXHR) {
            alert('Error: ' + jqXHR.status + '; Text: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }

    })
```

I added a success action with a transition to the index page and my ajax become like this

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/myProject/journals/doc/create',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("input[name='_csrf']").val()},
        data : JSON.stringify({document, plbTable}),

        success: function() {
            window.location.href = "/myProject/journals/doc";
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            alert('Error: ' + jqXHR.status + '; Text: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }

    })
```

and i removed redirect from `create(@RequestBody String dataToSave)` method

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public void create(@RequestBody String dataToSave) throws JsonProcessingException {

    // code to create object in database using JPARepository ...
    
}
```

And now link `window.location.href = "/myProject/journals/doc";` worked and i go to the index page.